# Binance Python API close order by id

Tags: python, binance-api-client

I need to close an order previously opened with:

```
order_id = "test"
symbol = "BTCUSDT"
direction = "long"
quantity = "0.1"

order = client.futures_create_order(newClientOrderId=order_id, symbol=symbol, side=direction, type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET, quantity=quantity)
```

Is there a way to say Binance to close it at market price like:

```
client.futures_close_order(orderId=order_id)
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have an OPEN order ( an order that is still waiting for filling), it's easy to cancel via endpoint `DELETE /fapi/v1/order`.
2. If you are referring to a position, you can place another order (can be MARKET, LIMIT, etc) to close it.